# How to execute code form markdown file in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, markdown

Is there plugin for PyCharm that can run code from markdown file? I would like to write some text, then make some calculations using python code and add result to my text. Then continue with my text.

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm professional version supports Jupyter notebooks, using the ["editor only"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html#editor) view mode gets pretty close to what you want.